# Alignment if li elements in a flex box css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying develop sidebar for my UI, In my sidebar container I took the width in 20vw so that it can be adjustable according to the screen sizes of different laptops and desktop. Next I take the `ul` as a container to enter first menu in the list item. I am using flex box.

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 30vw;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  min-width: 200px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 3px solid red;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 2rem;
}
li {
  background-color: #8cacea;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-balance-scale" style="font-size:24px"></i> </li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>+ </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to align icon and 2nd element to left side and + icon to the extreme right side which is not possible for me in flex box and second one is that when I reduce the screen size my elements overflow. I don't wrap the element I just want to shrink element at very small extant. When I use gap it evenly create gap all elements and when I tried margin-left:auto its doesn't maintain the gap in this case when I reduce the screen size gap doesn't consistent.
Please help to solve this issue.
I need the layout just in purchases menu in the image.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wanted to move the first two `li` to start of the webpage, i put those under a common parent `span` and applied styles accordingly.

check now.

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 30vw;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  min-width: 200px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 3px solid red;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}

.child1 {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  background-color: #8cacea;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <ul>
            <span class="child1">
              <li>
                <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" style="font-size:24px"></i>
              </li>
              <li>Home 1</li>
            </span>
            <li>+</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <span class="child1">
              <li>
                <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" style="font-size:24px"></i>
              </li>
              <li>Home 2</li>
            </span>
            <li>+</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you tell me one thing plz add new menu for sales and accounts will we have to take individual <ul> for each?

Comment: yes, you can use separate `ul` for each item, i updated the answer for 2 items

Comment: ok as in the above side menu image when we divide side bar in three portions top center and bottom, top for logo centre for menu items and third for bottom item anything else then basicaaly will we take three divs and for centre div{display:flex} for all ul elements for which centre div will be the parent of <ul> and ul will be the parent of all <li>  ?

Answer (score 0):

When wanting to position 2 elements on the same side and another element on the other side, I'd recommend grouping the 2 elements together. Furthermore I wouldn't place every single item in a different list item.

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;  
    outline: none;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  height:100vh;
  width:30vw;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  min-width:200px;
}


ul {
  list-style: none;
  border:3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2em;
  background-color: #8cacea;
}

li>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" style="font-size:24px"></i> 
            <p>Home</p>
          </div>
          <p>+</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" style="font-size:24px"></i> 
            <p>Other</p>
          </div>
          <p>+</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```